# Can I take the dog in the Magnum Opus?

Tags: mad-max

I really like the dog in Mad Max, but so far I can only take it out in chums rubbish buggy instead of the Magnum Opus. Is there a way (either as an in game upgrade or pc mod) to take the dog out in the Magnum Opus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dog is specifically bound to the buggy. Though modding is possible, however there is nobody actually doing any modding. So unless you make a mod yourself. I´m sorry you can not.